# pyLDAvis | Could I get "Top-30 Most Relevant Terms for Topic"?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, lda, topic-modeling

During the Topicmodeling visualization through LDAvis, I found that Slide to adjust relevance metric varies depending on the topic and lambda values. Is there a way to get this word list?
I want to get the representative words that vary depending on the lambda value.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this file, https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/blob/master/pyLDAvis/_prepare.py.

For example, you can do it like this:

```
vis_data = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(lda, corpus, dictionary)
print(vis_data.sorted_terms(topic=1, _lambda=0))
```